# How to check given time is after 3pm or not in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, datetime-comparison

I want easiest or simplest method which returns me boolean value (true/false) depending on the given time is after 3 pm or not irrespective of date.

for ex:-

```
   def after_three_pm(time)
     //some code here 
   end

   time= Time.now # Tue Jul 26 11:17:27 +0530 2011  THEN
   after_three_pm(time)  # should return false

   time= Time.now # Tue Jul 26 15:17:27 +0530 2011  THEN
   after_three_pm(time)  #  should return true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def after_three_pm(time)
  time.hour >= 15
end
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

you simply need to use the "time" function:

```
    Time.now.hour
=> 11
```

Now you can just evaluate this against the hour you want.