# Check if current time is before 10:27pm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Found many ways to check if the current hour is within an hour range. But how would you check if the current time is before a minute-specific time like `10:27 pm`

Current Code (only compares hours, not minutes):

```
Time.now.getlocal("-05:00").hour.between?(10, 22)
```

For example our store hours are `9:24am - 10:27pm` and we want to check if it is currently open.

Comment: If you want simple: `(hour*60)+minute < (hourGoal*60)+minuteGoal`
(Here `minute`, `hour`, `minuteGoal`, and `hourGoal` aren't actual variable, you would replace them by the full call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check given time is after 3pm or not in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828294/how-to-check-given-time-is-after-3pm-or-not-in-rails)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As clearly mentioned in [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#class-Time-label-Working+with+an+instance+of+Time):

> You can also do standard functions like compare two times.

I think you can do something like this:

```
require 'time'
close_time = Time.parse "10:27 pm"
#=> 2015-11-23 22:27:00 -0800
current_time = Time.now 
#=> 2015-11-23 19:38:06 -0800
current_time < close_time
#=> true # means the store is open

late_time = Time.now + 4*60*60
#=> 2015-11-23 23:39:15 -0800
late_time < close_time
#=> false # means the store is close
```